# If the result of FFT is like this, how should I mask?

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, fft, frequency

I am trying to apply **fft** to signal data and apply a **moving window** here.

First, let me show you the results.

**1) Original Signal (length : 120)**
[image: Original Signal (length : 120)]

**2) FFT Result**
[image]

I've been taught that the result of an FFT should be **symmetric**.

Therefore, I thought that if I wanted to apply a moving window from 1hz, I had to **mask the beginning and the end** of the array at the same time.

However, it is confirmed that the beginning and end of the FFT result **do not match** and the rest of the array values ​​are **also not symmetric.**

These are the array values ​​at the beginning and end of the FFT result.

[image]
[image]

**In conclusion, I would like to move the signal data to the frequency domain and proceed with the moving window in 1Hz increments. But how to deal with these results?**

Comment: Are you sure you're looking a the right data ? The graph looks symmetric, by eye, and the values in your array don't seem to be anywhere near the plotted values ? I suspect you're looking at the time domain values (FFT input), not the frequency domain (FFT output) ?

Comment: Looks like the array values stated as "at the beginning and end of the FFT result" (those we can see anyways) are pretty much exactly the tail ends of the "Original Signal" plot. And as Paul R noted matching index 1 with 119, 2 with 118, ... looks pretty symmetric. FFT Bin 0 of any real valued signal is purely real and has no symmetric counterpart, so disregard that line in the plot when looking for symmetry.